# Program design issue , filesystemwatcher, multithreading c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, filesystemwatcher

I am developing a c# program that uses FilesystemWatcher to monitor the PDF files that are added into a monitor_directory. Every time a file is added to a directory I add it to a BlockingQueue  that is popped continuously in another thread infinite while loop, it waits there for file paths to be added, after that I go on with processing the files, the final part of the PDF file processing is moving it to the output directory.

The dispatching thread:

```
    private static void ThreadProc(object param)
    {

        FileMonitorManager _this = (FileMonitorManager)param;
        FileProcessingManager processingManager = new FileProcessingManager();
        processingManager.RegisterProcessor(new ExcelFileProcessor());
        processingManager.RegisterProcessor(new PdfFileProcessor());

        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                var path = (string)_this.FileQueue.Dequeue();
                if (path == null)
                    break;
                bool b = processingManager.Process(path);
                if (!b)
                {
                    _this.FileQueue.Enqueue(path);
                    Console.WriteLine("\n\nError on file: " + path);
                }
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("\n\nSucces on file: " + path);

            }
            catch (System.Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

The Process function tests if the file exists, does some processing and moves the PDF file to the output directory.

I have faced two problems:
1. The On_Create event handler from the FileSystemWatcher is triggered TWICE so the BlockingQueue has the same entry twice, in this case in the processing routine I verify if the file hasn't been moved to the output directory ( because that is the final part of the processing consists in moving the file there), if so I carry on with the processing, if no I exit.
2. if for some reason I get an Error accessing the content of the file saying: the file is being used by another process I return FALSE from the Process function and add the file path again to the queue.

Now.. This works but it works kind of slow.. How can I do this multi-threaded by taking in consideration the 2 issues I've been facing..
**Edit:**
What if I get the event, add it to the queue, it gets popped, the queue is empty and then I get the same event again, the queue is empty so it gets added, and basically I get the same event processed TWICE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) **FileSystemWatcher** notifies you twice because file is updated in two steps: first the **data**, then the **metadata**. So you could check that the latest write was not already taken into account using something like:

```
File.GetLastWriteTime(file);
```

Or you could check for duplicates.

2) You're not using multithreading: you process one file at a time, so you could spawn some threads to execute the Process method, e.g. use:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem
```

Comment: You can keep a map associating each file to the last edited time. Then if you see that the last modification time, that you obtain using GetLastWriteTime, is the same as when you processed the file you know there is nothing to do and you can ignore. You could even cancel the current processing and restarts it with the current file if you think changes have happened.

Comment: Very interesting, does this strategy work for the same file being added again to the monitor directory? Does the writeTime remains the same if I carry the file all over the place? When do I clean the map? And in what case would I receive only one notification per file ? because I am currently getting only one, I don t know what it is happening

Comment: If the file is added again then its modification date will change so your code will know it must process it. What do you mean by "all over the place": on the same file-system, included network, should be OK (but not sure). You don't have to clean the map. The FileSystemWatcher can behave randomly (even missing notification under heavy load, not sure it is its fault or the underlying OS API) so yes you can have one or two notifications for what you'd define as a single update (I've observed this too on a network file-system).

Comment: The thing is that I get one notification for only one file,  repeatedly. Is it state anywhere on the something about the numbers of notifications that I should get?  All over the place: on the same filesystem, network etc.(yes)

Comment: No I don't think this is well defined and may depend on the current system load; it's why you have to build some safeguards yourself :(: wait a little before starting the processing, check if processing is running, cancel processing and replace by new one...

Answer (score 3):

FileSystemWatcher is notoriously chatty.

I think this is what I would do...

1. Check to see if the BlockingQueue already has an entry for the file in question before adding it a second time from the On_Create call.
2. Do you expect to have a lot of null paths in your Queue?  Hopefully the null check is just a precaution.  But don't Enqueue null paths if you can help it.
3. In your worker threads just Dequeue and process
4. If your worker thread gets an error processing it you can Enqueue it again or you may want to set it aside as an exceptional case since if you get enough unprocessable files they can hog your queue and slow you down as well.

An easy way to do this multithreaded is to just start a new task each time you Dequeue a path...

```
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                var path = (string) _this.FileQueue.Dequeue();
                if (path == null)
                    break;
                bool b = processingManager.Process(path);
                if (!b)
                {
                    _this.FileQueue.Enqueue(path);
                    Console.WriteLine("\n\nError on file: " + path);
                }
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("\n\nSucces on file: " + path);

            }
            catch (System.Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        });
```

For production code you'll also want to pass a cancellation token into the Task and have a mechanism for stopping the loop and Tasks.

Comment: I intentionally enqueue a null when I want the infinite looping to stop. Another question, is multithreading these IO operations going to make the program faster?

Comment: Assuming that processingManager.Process does CPU intensive work then almost certainly yes.  This assumes you are CPU bound...  If you are I/O bound then no.

Comment: @Pragmateek yeah it seems there is a new way of managing / using threads with every .NET release.

Comment: @A.K instead of enqueueing null, you can use the IsAddingCompleted property on the BlockingCollection.

Comment: .NET 3.5 here, no BlockingCollection